# Woocommerce use thumbnail issues child storefront theme

Tags: image, woocommerce

I have created a child theme based on Storefront Woocommerce 3.3. Without adding support image. 3500 images have been uploaded and only the original size exist

I added support theme in function and tried to create the thumbs via plugin

```
function iconic_modify_theme_support() {
    $theme_support = get_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    $theme_support = is_array( $theme_support ) ? $theme_support[0] : array();

    $theme_support['single_image_width'] = 320;
    $theme_support['thumbnail_image_width'] = 150;
    $theme_support['gallery_thumbnail_image_width'] = 50;

    remove_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', $theme_support );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'iconic_modify_theme_support', 10 );
```

when I use force thumbnail regenarate for an image produce
in database wp_option
woocommerce_thumbnail_cropping, uncropped,yes
thumbnail_crop,1, yes

100x100, 102x300, 150x150, 300x883 shouldn't 17x150 be created?

the 100x100 have been created because of wordpress (and not woocommerce) setting? is it possible to cancel that?

Front page, archive page, single product and in admin's dashboard products list load (src) the file of full image (for example 700x400) the image will be displayed in lower dimensions ( 150x100 for example) but it will load the big file image.

Server in upload folder doesn't have same image in different sizes ( image.jpg , image150x100.jpg image50x30.jpg )

I dont have anything in function.php about the size of image

in Single product page image is retrieved from woocommerce

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
```

in Archive product I get the image

```
                if( has_post_thumbnail() ){
                    the_post_thumbnail( 'shop_catalog', array( 'class' => 'visible_photo scale-with-grid' ) );
                } elseif ( wc_placeholder_img_src() ) {
                    echo wc_placeholder_img( 'shop_catalog' );
                }
```

**Is it possible to use gallery_thumbnail in admin's product list ?**

[image]

Comment: Can you write in short what do you want to achieve? Have large image in admin Products list?

Comment: My problem was that I had large images in admin products list (while i want to use thumbnail). For some reason the child theme from storefront wouldn't create thumbnails so the admin products list was showing the big images (at 40x40). I used force thumbnail regenerate and now the admin list will use thumbnails for image.

But it is cropped 150x150 how can i change to 300x200 non crop?
woocommerce 3.3 wordpress 4.9

Comment: Is your problem only on administration products list? What are your settings in Appearance -> Customize -> WooCommere ->Product Images ? Is it "Uncropped"? What are you settings in Settings -> Media -> Thumbnail size ? Try uncheck "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)".

Comment: settings -> media had cropped option checked for thumbnails, I thought only woocommerce option was needed ( didn't know about settings-> media). And I can edit the width and height of the images .Thanks very much

Comment: Great. You are welcome. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Settings -> Media -> Thumbnail size uncheck "Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)".